# Running jQuery Ajax from Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site is working pretty slow, what I have done is that I have a textarea that I want to get auto-saved to in the database. I am doing jQuery Ajax calls to auto-save the textarea content.

My event on the textarea is the following:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#notepad',function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    Api.request({ handler: 'user', action: 'notepad', text: text });
});
```

The problem is that if I fast type "Hello World!", then it will be lagging due to the 12 needed ajax calls.

I have in that case tried to use the `abort()` method in jQuery Ajax, but it doesn't seems to work, as none of the calls actually gets cancelled.

My code is the following:

```
function Api(){
    this.current = $.ajax();
    this.request = function(options, apiCallback){
        // default arguments
        options = typeof options !== 'undefined' ? options : {};
        apiCallback = typeof apiCallback !== 'undefined' ? apiCallback : function(){};

        this.current.abort();
        this.current = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "api?"+new Date().getTime(),
            data: options,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            apiCallback(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            apiCallback({status: 'FAILED'});
        })
    };
}
var Api = new Api();
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this using a Javascript Object?

Comment: I haven't looked at abort but I bet that just cancels listening for the response. I am not sure why you want to autosave to the database. I would use cookies. Use a set interval while the textarea has focus to check for changes and save them ever few seconds. Then (if you still want to) use ajax to save in the database a lot less often. Don't forget to clearInterval when your textarea loses focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the last time the user typed, if time is up to 5 seconds, make an Ajax call ?

EDIT: Or just use a setInterval to save the textarea text using Ajax each X second ;)